# How can I delete my uploaded profile picture

Tags: support, images, gravatar

I like to delete my previous profile picture. How can I delete it? What about images uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com?

Comment: I don't know of any way to access previously uploaded profile pictures. Have you verified that it has not been deleted?

Comment: I can upload a new picture but I cannot delete them. there is no option when I click on change picture link.

Comment: I don't know that we can delete them. Same for all images.

Comment: Can you still access the old picture from the site in some way?

Comment: When I click on change picture link, I can see and select my old picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you upload a picture to use as a (Gra)vatar, it gets uploaded to SE's Imgur account.  In that sense, [it cannot be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94711/214632).

As an approximation, if you upload a *different* image (even if you do not use it), then that image will become your option for an "uploaded picture" (pushing your previous uploaded picture into the æther).